# Spring Integration Web Service Log SOAP Request Message (EVEN if the soap message is not correct)

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-integration

Could you tell me the way to log the SOAP message of , even if the message is not correct format ?

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.capgemini.manulife.integration.interceptor.LogInterceptor" />
</sws:interceptors>

<!-- inbound -->
<ws:inbound-gateway id="cas-inbound-gateway" request-channel="casRequestChannel" reply-channel="casResponseChannel" 
        marshaller="casMarshaller"        unmarshaller="casMarshaller"  />
<int:channel id="casRequestChannel">
     <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="SOAPLogChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="SOAPLogChannel" /> 
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" expression="payload" level="INFO" channel="SOAPLogChannel"/>
```

As you see, I already using PayloadLoggingInterceptor (LogInterceptor extends PayloadLoggingInterceptor ), but it did not go through PayloadLoggingInterceptor

Thank you and best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Spring Integration question, but more up to SOAP directly.

So, if your XML isn't with correct format, you don't have choice unless check it manually before unmarshalling.

So, you have to rely on the `simple` `<ws:inbound-gateway>` do the `<int-xml:validating-filter>` (or some other check) and only after that perform `<int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer>`.

Comment: I tried to set Jaxb2Unmarshaller Unmarshaller Listener, thought it can log the message before unmarshalling, but the listener is not designed for that purpose.

Comment: Can we use Servlet Filter to do it ?  I think it is possible. Trying it ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can add Filter to Spring Web Service using FilterRegistrationBean ^^